# How to create a custom layout with cards scrolling horizontal and posts scrolling vertically( recycler view ) which should work with pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZlNf.png)

**Here what I tried:**

I can able to achieve this layout using Wrapping Horizontal scroll view and recyclerview inside Nestedscroll view.

**The problem is :**

When I put recycler view inside any of the scrolling containers such as scroll view or Nested scroll view
Its loading all the items in recylerview at once which is not a implementation of recylerview,hence pagination is not achieved.

**Requirement:**

- 1.Top header cards should scroll horizontally which is of a (fixed) Limited size.
- 2.Label for the vertical scroll view
- 3.Recycler view for vertical scroll of items

All the above should scroll vertically.Please help, or suggest any better way doing this layouot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZlNf.png)

Comment: Horizontal `RecyclerView` inside a Vertical `RecyclerView` ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by having parent layout as `<nestedScrollView>` and in child you can take 2 recycler view of which one of them should be horizontal and another should be vertical.

set property `android:nestedScrollingEnabled:true` and your are good to go.